# Can not construct instance of org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.SimpleType, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated

Tags: java, angularjs

Im Working on uploading Multiple Images At a Time . By Passing params in a Form, I'm getting bellow Error :

Unknown error: Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.SimpleType, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@d989d0d; line: 1, column: 44]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.SimpleType, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@d989d0d; line: 1, column: 44]

My Code Is Angular JS Code.

```
    $scope.uploadFilesInForm = function(ownerFile,fileName){


                    $scope.fileUpload = {};
                    $scope.fileUpload.name = fileName;
                    $scope.fileUpload.description = 'sdsdsdsdssd';
                    $scope.fileUpload.images = ownerFile;
                    console.log("formData-----"+JSON.stringify($scope.fileUpload));
                    var passingParam = angular.copy($scope.fileUpload);
                    console.log("passingParam-----"+JSON.stringify(passingParam));
                    forImages.forImages({}, passingParam, function success(data) {
                                console.log("Inside Service -----"+JSON.stringify(data));
                            }); 
                }



    Service Code :


    services.service('forImages', function($resource) {
                    return $resource("services/admin/uploadFiles", { 
                    }, {
                        forImages : {
                            isArray : true,
                            method : "POST",
                            enctype : "multipart/form-data"
                        }
                    });
                });


    Java Controller Code : 

        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFiles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public void upload(@RequestBody UploadFilesForm UploadFilesForm) {
                    System.out.println("Uploaded File: "+ UploadFilesForm);
              // Code For Uploading Images.

            }


Java Form Code : 
public class UploadFilesForm extends Entity 
{
    private String name;

    private String description;

    private MultipartFile images;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public MultipartFile getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(MultipartFile images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
    public UploadFilesForm(@JsonProperty("images")MultipartFile images) {
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UploadFilesForm [name=" + name + ", description=" + description
                + ", images=" + images + "]";
    }


}
```

Comment: if you want to create an instance of an abstract class, you'll need to create an (anonymous) subclass. You can't instantiate them directly